# How to toggle a div that is hidden on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the following js to hide and show my div

```
function myFunction(test) {
    var x = document.getElementById(test);

    if (x.style.display == "none") {
        //x.style.display = "block";
        x.style.setProperty("display", "block", "important")
    } else {
        //x.style.display = "none";
        x.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important")
    }
}
```

I have all divs hidden on load using a class, which works, but you have to click a link twice to get it to unhide. How can I fix this to unhide on the first click?

The page Im working on is here, you can click on any of the titles to expand some section. (Ignore the formatting, it's very much a work in progress.)

http://thinkularity.eth.link

Comment: How is this function used?  `you have to click a link twice`  How have you attached this function to the link?

Comment: The problem is that `if (x.style.display == "none")` is literally just checking the element's `style` attribute - and it doesn't have one initially, since it is hidden via a CSS rule on its class. It works the second time because the function, the first time it runs, adds the `display: none` to its style attribute. (Look at it in the devtools element inspector as you click.) To fix it, you can look at the answers to [this question](if (x.style.display == "none")) - or, as a quick and dirty way, simply add an inline `display: none;` to each element initially rather than use the CSS class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very trivial and simple way to solve your problem is to **first** test `if (x.style.display == "block")` and if it is anything else to then display the hidden content. Another way is to include the style inline inside the html code so that the style property of the DOM object has some initial property immediately after rendering.

```js
function myFunction(test) {
    var x = document.getElementById(test);
    if (x.style.display == "block") { 
        x.style.display = "none"; 
    } else { 
        x.style.display = "block"; 
    }
}
```

```css
#test {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<h3 onclick="myFunction('test')">Click to toggle display</h3><br>
<div id="test">Now you see me</div><br>
```

Comment: @robinZigmond already raised the issue regarding your code in comments to the OP.

Comment: @GilbertOsborne, welcome. You can still select an answer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Better if you create another *class* to show the element and toggle that *class* on each click using [**`DOMTokenList.toggle()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle):

> The `toggle()` method of the [**`DOMTokenList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) interface removes a given token from the list and returns `false`. If token doesn't exist it's added and the function returns `true`.

**Demo:**

```js
function myFunction(test) {
  var x = document.getElementById(test);
  x.classList.toggle('showElement');
}
```

```css
.showNotes{
  display: none;
}
.showElement{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<h2><a onclick="myFunction('e23')" href="#23">023 Autonomy Day</a></h2>
<div class="showNotes" id="e23">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
<h2><a onclick="myFunction('e22')" href="#22">022 Skateboarding In An Embassy</a></h2>
<div class="showNotes" id="e22">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the check before applying the style. On the first click, the element is set to `display: none` because on pageload, the element has no `display` property set, so when your code checks `if (x.style.display == "none")`, it gets `false` - so it sets it to `display: none`. Using the `style` property of a Node references the actual `style` property of the HTML element, and does *not* include CSS properties.

I would personally create two classes, `.hidden` and `.visible`, and use `Node.classList.toggle` to toggle the element class, but your approach works too.

We can change your `if / else` to a `switch/case` (or `if / else if / else`) to set a default action if an element has no `style.display` property set - instead of hiding it by default, which is what was happening here, we will set `display: block` by default.

```js
function toggleHide(test) {
  var x = document.getElementById(test);

  var newValue;
  var visible = "block";
  var hidden = "none";
  
  switch(x.style.display) {
    case hidden:
      // show if hidden
      newValue = visible;
      break;
    
    case visible:
      // hide if visible
      newValue = hidden;
      break;
    
    default:
      // visible if style.display not set yet
      newValue = visible;
      break;
  }
  
  // clear out style.display
  x.style.setProperty("display", "");
  // set new value
  x.style.setProperty("display", newValue);
}

// call toggleHide on header click
document.getElementById("header").addEventListener("click",
  e => toggleHide("abc")
);
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Click me</h1>
<p id="abc" class="dropdown">This is hidden by default</p>
```